# Complete minimal example for using quickCheckAll

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I could use a complete example of how to use `quickCheckAll`. Here's what I've tried so far:

In a file `A.hs`:

```
module A where
    import Test.QuickCheck

    prop_a = 1 == 0

    check = do
        return []
        $quickCheckAll
```

In another file that's supposed to drive the tests:

```
import A

main :: IO ()
main = do
    check
```

This doesn't work, because check doesn't have type `IO ()`. How I am supposed to "execute check" as instructed [in the documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.7.6/docs/Test-QuickCheck-All.html)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you misread [the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.9.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck-All.html#v:quickCheckAll) a bit. It specifies that you should write `return []` as a naked expression, and that you have to use `TemplateHaskell`:

> Test all properties in the current module, using Template Haskell. **You need to have a `{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}` pragma in your module** for any of these to work.
>
> (...)
>
> To use `quickCheckAll`, add a definition to your module along the lines
>   of
>
> ```
> return []
> runTests = $quickCheckAll
> ```
>
> and then execute `runTests`.
>
> (...)
>
> Note: the bizarre `return []` in the example above is needed on GHC 7.8; **without it, `quickCheckAll` will not be able to find any of the properties**. For the curious, the `return []` is a Template Haskell splice that **makes GHC insert the empty list of declarations at that point in the program**; GHC typechecks everything before the `return []` before it starts on the rest of the module, which means that the later call to `quickCheckAll` can see everything that was **defined before the `return []`**. Yikes!

So your first file should be:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module A where

import Test.QuickCheck

prop_a = 1 == 0

return []
check = $quickCheckAll
```

all properties you want to test (here `prop_a`) should be defined before the `return []`.

and the main file:

```
import A

main :: IO Bool
main = check
```

You are allowed to use `do`, but it does not add any value. Or in case you want the `main` to be `IO ()`, you can write:

```
import A

main :: IO ()
main = do
    check
    return ()
```

Running this in `ghci` gives:

```
*A> :t check
check :: IO Bool
*A> check
=== prop_a from ha.hs:7 ===
*** Failed! Falsifiable (after 1 test):  

False
```

Comment: Indeed, I got confused. Thank you. I found out thought that I had to edit the function main: `main = do check; return ()` to give it type IO (). `check` has type IO Bool

Comment: @GuillaumeChérel: as far as I know any `IO a` as `main` is acceptable. But indeed now it conflicts with the type signature.